# PWA + IndexedDB + Angular 9 website integration issues

Tags: progressive-web-apps, indexeddb, angular9

I am new to PWA integration. Gone through few videos/tuts of indexed db integration with Angular for adding PWA support in application.

**Requirement :**

1. Check if we are able to add data from website (crud add/edit pages) for offline mode.
2. Saved offline data should be accessible when user comes online.

**Challenges :**

1) Not getting correct way to add indexed db integration in Angular. Started with create database/ get /delete  / update database processes from main.ts

2) Can somebody guide correct way of using indexed db in angular 9 ?

Thanks,
Monika

Comment: That is more of a tutorial question than what could be answered here. Have you tried a google search for 'indexeddb angular'? That will give you many examples and some tutorials that may help.

Comment: We tried tuts/videos for 'indexeddb with angular 9' . Not able to get a way for 
1) Check if we are able to add data from website (crud add/edit pages) for offline mode.

2) Saved offline data should be accessible when user comes online

Comment: @MonikaKumbhar check this and try https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OkpWw7gbPtk

Answer (score -1):

Run this code to install the IndexedDB
Npm install idb
 
Refer this URL to inderstand this database
https://www.npmjs.com/package/idb

Indexed-db.service.ts
This is a basically a utility for all data base handling related indexedDB. 
 
Offline.service.ts
This service will take care of all offline and online events using an event listener

Comment: create a Offline.service.ts.
This service will take care of all offline and online events using an event listener